# Why goroutine pause for several minutes

Tags: go, amazon-s3, concurrency, goroutine

I have a task written in GO to read .gz files from AWS S3, size of each .gz file will be **20M**.

Each goroutine will download a .gz file from s3 to local disk, then read its content line by line via gzip.NewReader.

When task(goroutine) count exceeds 70, 67 goroutine will finish their operations successfully. But the remain goroutine then will be ***paused*** for several minutes.

At the moment it paused, I saw CPU is 100%, and then, CPU will low down to 0.2%(4CPU, 16G Memory) to stay for several minutes.

***Question***: I'm confused that, why goroutines doing nothing at that time with CPU quite low? What may cause this?

```
Test results:
60 goroutines, it will finish successfully in 27 seconds;
70 goroutines, it will finish successfully in 30s;
80 goroutines, 77 of them will finish successfully in 30s, but the remaining 3 will **pause 4 minutes**, then restart and finish in 10s
```

Code as below:

Main goroutine:

```
    func main() {
      runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()*2)
      chs := make([]chan string, 70)
      for i:=min; i<max; i++ {
          chs[i] = make(chan string, 1)
          go readobj.Reads3obj(i, chs[i])
      }
      for _, ch := range chs {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
      }
    }
```

ReadObject:

```
func Reads3obj(s3KeyName, ch chan string) {
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
              Region: aws.String("x"),
              Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("x", "x", "")},)

    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

    //create a zipFile to download from S3 to local
    zipFile, err := os.Create(zipname)

    //download .gz file from S3
    n, err := downloader.Download(zipFile, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(s3KeyName),
    })
    //create a file reader
    fileReader, err := os.Open(zipFile)

    //create a gzip reader      
    gzipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(fileReader)

    //create a buffered reader
    buf := bufio.NewReader(gzipReader)

    //read zip file line by line
    for line, isPrefix, err := []byte{0}, false, error(nil); len(line) > 0 && err == nil; {
        line, isPrefix, err = buf.ReadLine()
       //insert line to ES
    }
  }
```

EDITED:
When it paused, opened file count is quite small, so I think the opened files didn't exceeds most and it won't matters. Because:

The output of `ll /proc/PID/fd` is

```
zc@ip-xxx:/proc/18059/fd$ ll
total 0
dr-x------ 2 zc zc  0 Dec 26 06:50 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 zc zc  0 Dec 26 06:50 ../
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 12 -> 
/home/zc/75.gz
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 21 -> 
/home/zc/78.gz
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 253 -> socket:[76054]
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 280 -> socket:[77064]
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 47 -> 
/home/zc/58.gz
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 65 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 zc zc 64 Dec 26 06:50 93 -> socket:[75984]
```

Comment: Ask the profiler: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/#pkg-overview

Comment: There no reason to start 70 concurrent streams from S3. Even if it’s not the root problem, it’s making your performance far worse than it could be.

Comment: If you want to see why it’s blocked, start by looking at the stack trace while it’s blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Golang gzip library read file in one goroutine,

So big file occupy the cpu for long time on 100%. Use [pzip](https://github.com/klauspost/pgzip) instead.

Use as a replacement for gzip, exchange

```
  import "compress/gzip"
```

with

```
 import gzip "github.com/klauspost/pgzip".
```

Comment: Thanks for your info. I tried but unfortunately, the program is still stucked. This time when it paused, max utilization of 1 cpu is only 75%, the other 3 cpu is low, around 50%, all less then 100%...I'm still confused what is wrong with it =.=

Comment: There is some parameters to play with. Block size etc.